# How to use bootstarp toggle for checkbox using laravel yajra datatable

Tags: laravel-5, yajra-datatable

I'm using `yajra/datatables`, `yajra/datatables-html`, `yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle`.

I have followed the yajra/datatables-html tutorial for "edit column" with bootstraptoogle attribute and also included bootstarp toogle of js with css but bootstarp toogle is not working.

Maybe i'm missing something because if I try to show the table via Controller I can see teh data, but of course on checkbox button bootstrap toogle is not applied.

```
PHP Version: 7.1.3
Laravel Version: 5.8
Yajra/laravel-datatables Version: ^1.5
Yajra/laravel-datatables-html Version: ^4.4
Yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle Version: ^9.2
```

This is my Blade file code

```
{!! $html->table(['class'=>'table table-hover datatable mdl-data-table dataTable']) !!}
```

This is my controller function

```
use DataTables;
use App\Doctor;`enter code here`
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder;

/**
 * Build DataTable class.
 *
 */
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function doctor(Builder $builder)
    {
        if (request()->ajax()) {
            $model = Doctor::query();

            return DataTables::eloquent($model)
                ->editColumn('status', function(Doctor $doctor) {
                    $checkedStatus = ($doctor->status == 1) ? 'checked' : '';
                    return '<input type="checkbox" id="dl-admin-toggle" "'.$checkedStatus.'" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" />';
                })
                ->rawColumns(['status'])
                ->toJson();
        } 

        $page_title = 'Doctor';
        $html = $builder->columns([
                                    ['data' => 'id', 'name' => 'Id', 'title'=>'Invoice Link'],
                                    ['data' => 'name', 'name' => 'Fisrt Name', 'title'=>'First Name'],
                                    ['data' => 'status', 'name' => 'Status', 'title'=>'Status']
                                 ])->parameter([
                                    'initComplete'=> 'function() {
                                        $('.dl-admin-toggle').bootstrapToggle()
                                    }
                                ]);

        return view('admin.doctor', compact('html','page_title'));
    }
}
```